# How to make an API request with another API result in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

How can I make an API request with results from another API?

This is for a historical weather application. I want to use three APIs, one for latitude and longitude, another which requires parameters latitude & longitude and returns nearby id station, and the last one what requires id station parameters from the second one and returns temperature.

```
 async componentDidMount(){
        axios
        .get('https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=' + WEATHER_KEY + '&q=' + 'navodari')
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ lat: res.data.location.lat,
                            lon: res.data.location.lon
                         });
          return axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/stations/nearby?lat='+ this.state.lat+'&lon'+ this.state.lon +'&limit=1&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ station: res.data.id });
          return axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/daily?station=' + this.state.station + '&start=' +this.state.start + '&end=' +this.state.start+ '&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ temp: response.data.temperature});
          console.log(this.state.temp);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

I expected to make the state temp with `response.data.temperature`, but it gives me an error that

> station is undefined.("400 BAD REQUEST")

Could you please advise me on the correct solution?

Comment: Hi @AnghelMarius Welcome to StackOverflow. For a format guides, check out this post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Look into the keyword `await` to wait for the response from the API call and access the data

`let response = await axios.get(...)`
`let someDataINeed = response.data.element`
`let secondResponse = await axios.get(... using someDataINeed here ...)`
`let secondResponseData = secondResponse.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution posted by Vijay Menon should work, but calling setState multiple times will cause multiple renders which could be less efficient. Also, using async/await in a different way can make the code more readable:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try {
        const latlongdata = await axios.get('https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=' + WEATHER_KEY + '&q=' + 'navodari');
        const lat = latlongdata.data.location.lat;
        const lon = latlondata.data.location.lon;
        const stationdata = await axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/stations/nearby?lat=' + lat + '&lon' + lon + '&limit=1&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        const station = stationdata.data.id;
        const tempdata = await axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/daily?station=' + this.state.station + '&start=' + this.state.start + '&end=' + this.state.start + '&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        const temp = tempdata.data.temperature;
        this.setState({
            lat,
            lon,
            station,
            temp
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i deal with this error " Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'const'" at line with "const tempdata" ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a comma after stationdata.data.id which was wrong. Change that to a semi-colon and it should fix that error. I have edited my code above.

Comment: @mark Saltzman, I agree . If the lat,lon and station variables are used only for calling the next API's and not for any UI changes, your approach would be more efficient.

Comment: @angelmarius, let us know if you got this working .

Answer (score 1):

Something like below where you use async/await and call the next API within a callback for the previous setState to make sure that the state is updated (as state updates are also asynchronous):

```
async componentDidMount(){
  let latlongdata ,stationdata,tempdata;
try {
        latlongdata = axios.get('https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=' + WEATHER_KEY + '&q=' + 'navodari')
          this.setState({ lat: latlongdata.data.location.lat,
                            lon: latlongdata .data.location.lon
                         },() => {
      stationdata = axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/stations/nearby?lat='+ this.state.lat+'&lon'+ this.state.lon +'&limit=1&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        this.setState({ station : stationdata.data.id },() {
         tempdata = axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/daily?station=' + this.state.station + '&start=' +this.state.start + '&end=' +this.state.start+ '&key=' + STATION_KEY);
      this.setState({ temp: tempdata.data.temperature});
 });
});
} catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
}
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error like this "Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Comment: ok, so did you debug the error? Where is the error coming from?